# I'm trying to show an image but it wont work?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to show an image to make a voiceover AI for YouTube, however this code from the course I'm following doesn't seem to be working

```
from IPython.display import display, Image

display_handle = display(None, display_id = True)

for frame in base64Frames:
    display_handle.update(Image(data = base64.b64decode(frame.encode("utf-8"))))
```

it's exactly as they've typed it however mines an error and theirs doesnt seem to be?

I'm using VScode on windows 10 if that makes any difference

It just comes up with an error message of

```
    display_handle.update(Image(data = base64.b64decode(frame.encode("utf-8"))))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

I'm not sure why as I think I've wrote it all right

Comment: Are you doing this from inside an IDE?  Which one?  `IPython.display.display` acts very differently depending on where it is called.

Comment: I'm using visual code studio, the course is using colab?

Comment: That's the difference.  There are other ways to display images if you're not in IPython environment, like PIL or OpenCV.

Comment: You can use jupyter notebooks from within VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

Comment: The error indicates that `display_handle` variable is `None`.   And I believe @TimRoberts already explained why so and gave you alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `PIL` imaging python library, like this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(r"path to your image") #r to convert it to a raw string
im.show() #shows the image
```

and this might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I made some modifications to the previous code.
Now, it uses display_handle.display(Image(data=img_data)) instead of display_handle.update(Image(data=img_data)). This change is made to display the image rather than updating the display. Try this code and check if it displays the images as expected.

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
import base64

display_handle = display(None, display_id=True)

for frame in base64Frames:
    img_data = base64.b64decode(frame.encode("utf-8"))
    display_handle.display(Image(data=img_data))
```

Comment: unfortunately, I'm basically getting the same error :(

display_handle.display(Image(data=img_data))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display'

sorry idk how to embed the code like you have